# How to add shadow on overlapped layout?

Tags: android, layout, shadow

How to add shadow on overlapped layout? I try to use elevation but it doesn't work
[image]

Comment: add some of your code trying this thing

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Yes but doesn't work

Comment: The point is I want to change the elevation's shadow from bottom to top side... (Sorry for my bad English)